# Why deploying Apache Camel in Apache Karaf is not working?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoCuyvRfw20) carefully to deploy Apache Camel Hello World in Apache Karaf in in Windows 7. But it is not working as expected. The Apache Karaf console not show the stream message from Camel route.
This is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpise.jpg) from karaf console which not show anything.

Comment: the screenshot is taken after restart my Apache Karaf, camel feature was installed before.

Comment: The screenshot does not show anything and please share any logs and more detailed info of what you are doing and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The output of karaf is shown when you enter: 
log:display 
(or ld for short)